# document.querySelector('a').innerHTML but how do I change the code so that it will find the 2nd or 3rd link, instead of just the first?

Tags: javascript, dom

document.querySelector('a').innerHTML

That's an example, but how do I change the code so that it will find the 2nd or 3rd link, instead of just the first?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you must a) have researched the question to no avail, b) have attempted to resolve the problem with code, and c) having not been able to solve the issue you're having you must post at least one attempt within the question itself so we can see what you've done.

Comment: .querySelectorAll() to the rescue

Comment: Thank you @zfrisch ! As a newbie SO had me "post [my] first question" so I submitted my question that I was in the middle of researching. It didn't take much research for me to discover I was woefully naive. Thanks for your patience, I'm eager to shed my ignorance :)

Answer (score 0):

With something similar to this.
But as pointed by @zfrisch, your post is missing vital information for people to participate in this discussion.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="goingsomewhere.html">go somewhere</a><br>
  <a href="goingsomewhereelse.html">go somewhere else</a><br />
  <a href="notgoinganywhere.html">dont go anywhere</a>

  <script>
  var thelinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');//aggregate all your links into an array
  for(var i = 0; i < thelinks.length; i++)//iterate through them
  {
      console.log(thelinks[i]);
  }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned to zfrisch, as a newbie SO had me "post [my] first question" so I submitted my question that I was in the middle of researching. Thanks for being patient with me and giving me some great pointers.